# Why does NSFetchedResultsController not conform to the UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Tags: iphone, core-data

First I thought I've grocked that thing: It's the data source for a UITableView. But then: It does not conform to that data source protocol. Strange! Why? How can it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is not a data source. It's the intermediary between the data source and the `UITableView`. For example, it can notify the `UITableView` when its data source changes. This prevents coupling between the data source the `UITableView`, which would violate the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: So NSFetchedResultsController establishes the link to the Data Source?

Comment: It doesn't establish the link, you do programatically. After the `NSFetchedResultsController` maintains the links, updating the view or data source when the other changes. Roughly.